# How to print pdf exported from jasper report in Epson TM-m30II?

Tags: pdf, printing, epson

I have a **pdf** report exported from **jasper** report with the ability to make jasper export different files formats like HTML or image, how to print the exported file directly in **Epson** TM-m30II?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm trying to print through the angular application I forgot to mention this point

Answer (score 0):

Print Directly sounds like you want to do it the hard way.

Epson have used Man Centuries developing drivers and SDKs so use one of those otherwise one man month will not not be enough for working through all the wrinkles that model should accept two comms languages.

```
The printer supports the following command systems:
• ePOS-Print XML 
• ESC/POS
```

Use the most appropriate firmware and software found here

https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=prod&pcat=3&pid=6370

beware there are multiple models that will respond differently to some codes but if you are sure it is the very basic model (not -H or -S etc.) then read the standard model manual

https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_doc&cid=6643&dcat=22&pcat=3